# View titanium code in xcode format

Tags: xcode, titanium

Is there a way to view the code typed in titanium in the xCode format? If so, which file should I check out under ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

This is the beauty of titanium that it uses the native code and you could run its project in xcode too.Double click on the ProjectName.xcodeproj and it would open your project in xcode and then you can run code from there

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> In the build/iphone directory, you'll find an xcodeproj file.
>   Double-click it to open the project in Xcode. However, you might not
>   want to do your final build in Xcode. You'll lose internationalization
>   and perhaps other Titanium features that way. You can do you final
>   packaging in Studio. If they're not already installed into Xcode,
>   Studio will prompt you for your distribution certificate and
>   provisioning file. It will build your final IPA using the Build &
>   Archive equivalent of Xcode. You can use the Xcode Organizer then to
>   validate and upload the IPA. Or, use the
>   Developer/Applications/Application Loader tool to upload your IPA to
>   iTunes Connect

Reference : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122926/open-appcelerator-project-in-xcode